# How to exclude specific tr with class name from td(s) selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a HTML code which is having table, tr and td, I need to select all the tds excluding those which are in tr of class 'Header', 'Header' is class of tr.

I am using following code but its not working

```
$("table .dataGrid td").not("tr .Header")
```

Thanks

Comment: why not put the tr with `.header` in `thead` and the rest to `tbody`?then just select everything in tbody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("table tr.dataGrid:not(.Header) td")
```

Will select all `td` who are not the child of `tr.Header`

Comment: you made the table row (tr) a class .tr :)

Comment: Now i'm just being annoying but he might want to keep the .dataGrid selector so make it .dataGrid tr:not(.Header), if you want of course

Comment: @LiviuBoboia This worked for me but probably not a optimum way (code change to actual classes as per actual code) $("table .dataGrid td").not(":has(a)").not($("tr .dgHdr").children("td")).not($("tr .prevnext").children("td"))  Any thoughts?

Comment: I didn't get you? Why it is not a optimum way?

Comment: @LiviuBoboia This worked perfectly, thanks for giving idea  $("table .dataGrid tr:not(.dgHdr,.prevnext) td").not(":has(a)").on("click", function () {

Comment: Why you mentioning @LiviuBoboia ?

Comment: @void answered your question, if this works for you please accept his answer

Comment: @LiviuBoboia  its so confusing. :( :P